# Configuration fallback for environment value

Tags: rust, configuration

Is there a better practice for using a fallback value in a crate when a user environment value isn't present?

---

*My current thoughts are to treat it as an ternary condition and use a `match` or `if else` statement.*

```
const DEFAULT_VALUE: &'static str = "foobar";
let env_value: &str = &env::var("ENV_VALUE").unwrap();

let in_use_a = match env_value.len() > 0 {
  true => env_value,
  false => DEFAULT_VALUE,
};

let in_use_b = if env_value.len() > 0 { env_value } else { DEFAULT_VALUE };
```

Comment: When the environment variable is not present, `unwrap()` will call panic. Why don't you use  `unwrap_or`, e.g. `env::var("NAME").unwrap_or(DEFAULT_VALUE)`?

Comment: @Zeta I agree `unwrap_or` shorter and readable.  Please add your response as an answer, I have a feeling that is the best practice.  You will need to apply `to_string()` on the `DEFAULT_VALUE`.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know whether your code is even on-topic at the moment, as it's mostly example code. If you can rewrite it as `fn get_env_or_default(…)` (e.g. how you would write it in _real_ code), it's perfectly on-topic. I don't know enough Rust to distinguish your code from non-example code, sorry. But Shepmaster should be around soon.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty.  I guess I feel differently, this is the code minus actual name values because its only needed for this one off variable in the crate.  If I were to do it large scale configuration I would definitely need something more.  But I feels I got my answer by your suggestion of using the trait that has the conditions already defined for a default response.

Answer (score 2):

You state (emphasis mine)

> when a user environment value **isn't present**

But that's *not what your code does*. Your code puts in a default value when the value is present but **empty**. Right now, it will panic when the environment variable is not set.

If you wanted to handle the variable not being set, I'd use `unwrap_or`, as stated in the comments:

```
let env_value = env::var("ENV_VALUE");
let env_value = env_value
    .as_ref()
    .map(String::as_str)
    .unwrap_or("foobar");
```

I also choose to shadow the owned version of `env_value` with the reference to the `&str`.

Since you don't care about the way in which the variable failed, you can convert from a `Result` to an `Option`:

```
let env_value = env::var("ENV_VALUE").ok();
let env_value = env_value
    .as_ref()
    .map(String::as_str)        
    .unwrap_or("foobar");
```

If you did care to treat empty strings as an unset variable, you can throw an `and_then` in the mix:

```
let env_value = env::var("ENV_VALUE").ok();
let env_value = env_value
    .as_ref()
    .map(String::as_str)        
    .and_then(|s| if s.is_empty() { None } else { Some(s) })
    .unwrap_or("foobar");
```

Other points:

1. Rust uses a 4-space indent. Please check out [Rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt).
2. Likewise, check out [Clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy), which automatically tells you about these other issues I was going to point out:

   ```
   warning: Constants have by default a `'static` lifetime
    --> src/main.rs:5:23
     |
   5 | const DEFAULT_VALUE: &'static str = "foobar";
     |                       ^^^^^^^ help: consider removing `'static`
     |
     = note: #[warn(const_static_lifetime)] on by default
     = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.169/index.html#const_static_lifetime

   warning: you seem to be trying to match on a boolean expression
     --> src/main.rs:8:16
      |
   8  |   let in_use_a = match env_value.len() > 0 {
      |  ________________^
   9  | |   true => env_value,
   10 | |   false => DEFAULT_VALUE,
   11 | | };
      | |_^ help: consider using an if/else expression: `if env_value.len() > 0 { env_value } else { DEFAULT_VALUE }`
      |
      = note: #[warn(match_bool)] on by default
      = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.169/index.html#match_bool

   warning: length comparison to zero
    --> src/main.rs:8:22
     |
   8 | let in_use_a = match env_value.len() > 0 {
     |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: using `is_empty` is more concise: `!env_value.is_empty()`
     |
     = note: #[warn(len_zero)] on by default
     = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.169/index.html#len_zero
   ```